# React-Redux page refresh redirects to login even though state exists

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux, state, refresh

I am building a backend admin app, and it will not stay on the correct route/page when refreshing the browser.

When the user logs in, it redirects to /dashboard, updates the state with user info and access token, sets a refresh token on the server in a httponly cookie.

When the access token expires and a route gets a 401 it calls check refresh token and gets a new access token and updates state. All of this works great except on refresh.

I believe it may have something to do with the HashRouter maybe? Not sure but I'm pulling out my hair because I'm sure it's something small I'm missing.

When visiting the page I've created a PrivateRoute for all traffic other than /login.

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {HashRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from "./components/PrivateRoute";
import './scss/style.scss';

const loading = (
    <div className="pt-3 text-center">
        <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
    </div>
)

// Pages
const Login = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/login/Login'));

// Containers
const TheLayout = React.lazy(() => import('./containers/TheLayout'));

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/login" name="Login" render={props => <Login {...props}/>}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path="/" name="Home" render={props => <TheLayout {...props}/>}/>
                    </Switch>
                </React.Suspense>
            </HashRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

In PrivateRoute is where I put the initial check whether there is the token and isLoggedIn state, if not it dispatches my refresh token function to update the state, which also functions properly, but still redirects to /login.

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import {eraseToken, getRefreshedToken} from "../store/auth";
import store from "../store";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
    console.log(req)
    const token = store.getState().auth.user.token;
    if (token) {
        req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    } else {
        //req.headers.Authorization = null;
    }
    return req;
});

axios.interceptors.response.use(res => {
        return res;
    }, async (error) => {
        if (401 === error.response.status) {
            if ('/refresh' !== error.response.config.url) {
                await store.dispatch(getRefreshedToken());
            } else {
                store.dispatch(eraseToken());
            }
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }
);

const PrivateRoute = ({render: Component, ...rest}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let token = useSelector(state => state.auth.user.token);
    let isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
    console.log(token, isLoggedIn);
    
    if (!isLoggedIn || !token) {
        dispatch(getRefreshedToken());
    }

    // check again after state update
    token = useSelector(state => state.auth.user.token);
    isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.auth.isLoggedIn);

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            (token && isLoggedIn)
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}}/>
        )}/>
    )
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

This is where I'm confused. Once I log in I get redirected fine to /dashboard because token etc exists in state, however if I refresh the page while at /dashboard it calls dispatch(getRefreshedToken()); **which works fine**, and updates the state with the correct values, which should then just render the component (I assumed) instead of redirecting back to /login.

If I manually change the url and replace /login with /dashboard it views the dashboard fine still as the state exists properly.

The PrivateRoute renders a component called TheLayout, which renders a component called TheContent which maps routes to views to display.

**routes.js**

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', exact: true, name: 'Home' },
  { path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard },
  { path: '/users', name: 'Users', component: Users }
]

export default routes;
```

**TheContent.js**

```
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
import {Redirect, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {CContainer, CFade} from '@coreui/react';

// routes config
import routes from '../routes';

const loading = (
    <div className="pt-3 text-center">
        <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
    </div>
)

const TheContent = () => {
    return (
        <main className="c-main">
            <CContainer fluid>
                <Suspense fallback={loading}>
                    <Switch>
                        {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                            return route.component && (
                                <Route
                                    key={idx}
                                    path={route.path}
                                    exact={route.exact}
                                    name={route.name}
                                    render={props => (
                                        <CFade>
                                            <route.component {...props} />
                                        </CFade>
                                    )}/>
                            )
                        })}
                        <Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard"/>
                    </Switch>
                </Suspense>
            </CContainer>
        </main>
    )
}

export default React.memo(TheContent);
```

Not sure if that might have something to do with it?

**UPDATE**

I realized that the code was not waiting on dispatch to finish updating the state, so I changed the PrivateRoute to instead use useEffect with dependencies, and got it working how I needed.

However, trying to understand useEffect better, it's firing my refresh and calling the server multiple times once my cookie expires. Is there any way to stop this from happening? Here is my updated Private Route.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({render: Component, ...rest}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
    let token = useSelector(state => state.auth.user.token);
    let isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
    let isRefreshingToken = useSelector(state => state.auth.isRefreshingToken);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isLoggedIn && !token && !isRefreshingToken) {
            (async () => {
                await dispatch(getRefreshedToken())
                    .catch(err => {
                        history.push('/login');
                    });
            })();
        }
    }, [token, isLoggedIn, isRefreshingToken, dispatch, history])

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            <Component {...props} />
        )}/>
    )
}
```